# Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.youtube.com" only in chromium

Tags: javascript, youtube, chromium

It seems I'm getting these 2 errors but only in chromium.

```
Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.youtube.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://lart.co.uk". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
```

Works fine in firefox, same problem even appears when I visit youtube's official developer site.

I'm using a youtube gallery plugin and instead of loading a video in an iframe it takes me directly to the youtube site, it's ok for a fall back I guess but it's not ideal.

There's a couple of posts [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=17325) about the problem but I don't quite understand, is this specifically a chromium issue? Is there anything I can do to stop the error?